# why filter function not working on li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://plnkr.co/edit/Hcdp24jLgdlOv2NlqyIG?p=preview

Hi

I am trying to filter my `li` using **only** filter function.I have one button (filter text).When I click on button I want to show only that `li` which have class `abc`.I tried like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            cursor: pointer;

        }

        .tabItem li {
            float: left;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .tabItem li.active {
            color: red;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        .hideDiv{
            display: none;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>


<button class="filter">filler</button>
<ul class="item">
    <li class="äbc">123</li>
    <li class="pp">12</li>
    <li class="äbc">78</li>
    <li class="äc">13</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $(function () {


        $('.filter').click(function () {
            var $items = $('.item li');
            //$items.hide().filter(filterClasses.join('')).show();
            var $newItem =$items.filter(function (i,item) {
                console.log(i)
                console.log(item)
                return $(item).hasClass('abc')
            })
            $($newItem).show();
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Expected output**

```
123

78
```

Comment: <li class="äbc"> is not the same as <li class="abc">. look at the 'a' letter

Comment: `äbc` !== `abc`.

Comment: could you share plunker

Comment: see this https://plnkr.co/edit/Hcdp24jLgdlOv2NlqyIG?p=preview

Comment: `$($newItem).show();` doesn't do anything if the elements are already showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that **äbc** AND **abc** are NOT equal. My guess is that you meant to say **abc** for the class name, and if that is the case here's a quick solution. Hope it helps!

```js
    $(function () {
        $('.filter').click(function () {
            var $items = $('.item li');
            var $newItem =$items.filter(function (i,item) {
                return !$(item).hasClass('abc');
            });
            $($newItem).hide();
        });
    });
```

```css
ul {
            list-style: none;
            cursor: pointer;

        }

        .tabItem li {
            float: left;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .tabItem li.active {
            color: red;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        .hideDiv{
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="filter">filler</button>
<ul class="item">
    <li class="abc">123</li>
    <li class="pp">12</li>
    <li class="abc">78</li>
    <li class="ac">13</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use,

```
$('.item li[class=abc]').show(); // Let it is abc not äbc
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.filter').click(function() {
    $('.item li').hide(); // hide all first
    $('.item li[class=abc]').show(); // then show only which are having abc class
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabItem li {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tabItem li.active {
  color: red;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.hideDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>



<button class="filter">filler</button>
<ul class="item">
  <li class="abc">123</li>
  <li class="pp">12</li>
  <li class="abc">78</li>
  <li class="ac">13</li>
</ul>
```

To match all occurrence which ends with `bc` then use [Ends-with-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) like,

```js
$(function() {
  $('.filter').click(function() {
    $('.item li').hide(); // hide all first
    $('.item li[class$=bc]').show(); // then show only which ends with bc in class name
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabItem li {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tabItem li.active {
  color: red;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.hideDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>



<button class="filter">filler</button>
<ul class="item">
  <li class="äbc">123</li>
  <li class="pp">12</li>
  <li class="äbc">78</li>
  <li class="äc">13</li>
</ul>
```

Using [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) but with condition `return $(item).hasClass('abc') || $(item).hasClass('äbc')`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.filter').click(function() {
    var $items = $('.item li');
    var $newItem = $items.hide() // hide all first
      .filter(function(i, item) {
        console.log(i);
        console.log(item);
        return $(item).hasClass('abc') || $(item).hasClass('äbc')
      });
    $($newItem).show();
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabItem li {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}

.tabItem li.active {
  color: red;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.hideDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<button class="filter">filler</button>
<ul class="item">
  <li class="äbc">123</li>
  <li class="pp">12</li>
  <li class="äbc">78</li>
  <li class="äc">13</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i want to use filter function

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Hcdp24jLgdlOv2NlqyIG?p=preview

Comment: Try my updated answer and snippet using filter option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide unfiltered li, try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .tabItem li {
            float: left;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .tabItem li.active {
            color: red;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        .hideDiv{
            display: none;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>


<button class="filter">filler</button>
<ul class="item">
    <li class="äbc">123</li>
    <li class="pp">12</li>
    <li class="äbc">78</li>
    <li class="äc">13</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.filter').click(function () {
            var $items = $('.item li');
            //$items.hide().filter(filterClasses.join('')).show();
            var $newItem =$items.filter(".äbc");
  $($items).hide();
             $($newItem).show();
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the $items.not('.abc').hide() to acheive you want

```
$(function() {
  $('.filter').click(function() {
    var $items = $('.item li');
    $items.not('.abc').hide();
  });
});
```

Here is working code:https://plnkr.co/edit/zutgyWjYbRoE0mnUOvE2?p=preview